# xHeaderBackButton goes back but transitions from screen 3 to screen 2 and then goes to 1

Tags: react-native, screen

I am a beginner and i was wondering how i could go from screen 3 to screen 1 instead its going with my custom transitions from screen 3 to 2 and then 1 all in transition. I want it to go from screen 3 to screen 1 : this is the button i use on screen 3. I overwrote the goBack() because i wanted it to go directly to screen 1. But it doesn't work. How can this be fixed?

```
    <HeaderBackButton
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("Profile");
          }}
        />
```

I hope someone can give me an answer and can give me different options. I am a beginner so explain it basic to me please.

Thanks for your time

**Edit 17 October!**

```
const screensChosenConfig = {
  duration: 0
};

const standardScreensConfig = {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
  timing: Animated.timing,
  useNativeDriver: true
};

 transitionConfig: sceneProps => ({
      transitionSpec:
        sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === "Account" ||
        sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === "ChangePassword"
          ? screensChosenConfig
          : standardScreensConfig,
      screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
        const { position, layout, scene } = sceneProps;

        const thisSceneIndex = scene.index;
        const width = layout.initWidth;

        const translateX = position.interpolate({
          inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex, thisSceneIndex + 1],
          outputRange: [width, 0, 0]
        });

        const opacity = position.interpolate({
          inputRange: [thisSceneIndex - 1, thisSceneIndex],
          outputRange: [0, 1]
        });

        const translateWithOpacity = {
          opacity,
          transform: [{ translateX }]
        };

        return translateWithOpacity;
      }
    })
```

Comment: If you are using react-naivgation you can simply use `navigation.popToTop()`

Comment: @Auticcat Hey Autticat you answered me before in another question, thanks for your time. Yeah sorry it is actually not screen 1. screen 1 is my login page, my profile page is screen 2. But i used `navigation.popToTop()` and  it still goes in a transition from screen 3 to 2 to 1, not from 3 to 1?

Comment: I created a demo project to test it out and it works flawlessly both with navigate("firstScreen") that with popToTop(), it doesn't show the second screen. What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @Auticcat Heey Thanks for your time doing that. Thanks to your answer i looked further into my code and i noticed that `screenInterpolator` is causing this. I edited my code so you can maybe see what the problem is. And on how it could work with this code. When i delete `screenInterpolator` it works perfect as you are seeing it

Comment: @Auticcat But i want it to work with screenInterpolator please, hope you can see where/what the problem is.

Comment: Can you also post the part with transitionConfig?

Comment: @Auticcat Thanks for your time! I edited my Question. As you can see i use a `duration: 0` for 2 screens. Hope you can find out why the problem is. When i removed ONLY the `screenInterpolator` the problem was gone as i said in the comments. Greetings from Amsterdam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of testing but wasn't able to achieve a non-painful solution.

This first solution only works if the screen you are navigating to is the `initalRouteName` of the stackNavigator. If used on any other screen, it will disable the fade-in animation to that screen.

Simply, add the screen you are navigating back to the ones  you are giving `screensChosenConfig`:

```
sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === "Account" ||
sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === "ChangePassword"||
sceneProps.scene.route.routeName ==="ProfileScreen"
    ? screensChosenConfig
    : standardScreensConfig
```

This is how it behaves:

`ProfileScreen` appears without animation.

The `SecondScreen` animates in.

The `ThirdScreen` animates in.

Inside the focused screen you call `navigate("ProfileScreen")`

`ProfileScreen` appears without the fading Out animation of the other screens.

EDIT.

If you need to navigate back to another screen, that's NOT the initialRouteName, the solution i tested was to add, inside EVERY screen of the stack, this `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ animatedIn: true })
}
```

With this i could simply check it inside the `transitionSpec`:

```
transitionSpec:
  sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === "Account" ||
  sceneProps.scene.route.routeName === "ChangePassword"||
  (sceneProps.scene.route.params&&sceneProps.scene.route.params.animatedIn)
    ? screensChosenConfig
    : standardScreensConfig,
```

Note that this will disable animations for simple goBack() through header

Comment: Thanks for your beautiful answer and for your time. Oke the problem is fixed but there are two things i don't like. 1. When i go back from Account to Profile there is no transition(i want standardScreensConfig). 2. When i want to go from Profile to Account/ChangePassword  there is the standard transition as if i didn't configure seperate transitions. It's just the standard ScreenToLeft transition. How can it be there as another transitions setting. I wish i could have it all under my control.

Comment: The second part of your code (EDIT) i want to try out. But the componentDidMount needs to go inside my page JS file? Or just in the App.js? And what does this exactly do? I will go from screen 3 to 1 without animation, that is what the purpose is for this code?

Comment: Also if i go from LogIn to Profile there is no transition because of `sceneProps.scene.route.routeName ==="ProfileScreen"` I am a perfectionist when it comes to design. So i really don't like this. Wish there was a better way

Comment: As said, the first solution will remove ANY animation that screen as, so if you navigate from 3 to 1 it will be instant, not sure about the why it's not using your transtion tho.

Comment: For the second one, you have to add it to all your scenes/screens/pages, app.js will not work. The second solution will give you a fade-in animation but every goBack, pop, popToTop, will be instant with no animation.  I'll check it tomorrow

Comment: Oke thankyou, too bad screenInterpolator makes it behave like this else there was no problem. The only thing i am thinking about is my ListItems which i set on a duration of 0. So you cant see its a different page. My question is, is there a way to go to different listItems without going to a different screen? I am a beginner so i dont know. Maybe i could switch between list items without having it going to a different screen? So all list items on 1 page and when selecting one listItem or a second it will behave inside 1 screen. Or is this impossible? Before you find another solution

Comment: i fixed it never mind. Fixed it by hiding and showing content on the same page

Comment: Can you help a friend of mine his question is not answered. I know you know the answer in a few minutes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452358/i-have-a-problem-with-saving-the-radio-button-when-the-radio-button-is-not-selec . He wIll give you points by accepting your answer.